# Shape of Ferrers Graph

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Do the positions of the outer corners of a Ferrers Graph suffice to determine the partition uniquely? What about the inner corners?

Shape of Ferrers Graphs: the contour is a horizontal line on top, a vertical line on the left and a ragged rim from the southwest corner to the northeast corner.

There are two kinds of corners on the rim: outer corners and inner corners.
The two endpoints of the rim are inner corners. The outer corners are squares that can be removed and it'll still be a Ferrers board. The inner corners are places where squares can be added and a new Ferrers board is formed.

Comment: The outer corners definitely determine the partition uniquely, because the points in the Ferrers diagram of the partition are precisely the points that can be reached from an outer corner by walking northwards and westwards.

Comment: The inner corners also determine the partition uniquely. Indeed, it suffices to check that the inner corners determine the outer corners uniquely. But this is easy: If you list out the inner corners from southwest to northeast, then there is exactly one outer corner between every pair of consecutive inner corners, and you can tell explicitly where this outer corner is (exercise!).

Comment: Note: What you call "Ferrers graph" is commonly known as a Ferrers diagram. It is not a graph in the usual sense of the word.